# complain when a property not declared in propTypes is passed to a component

Tags: reactjs

React components raise an error when a required property declared in `propTypes` is not passed (or if it is passed with the wrong type).

Is there a way to configure React so that components also complain when they receive additional properties over those declared in `propTypes` ?

E.g. I would like the following to break:

```
// some render method in some other component:

    , render: function() {
        return (<Foo someString='foo' extraProp='bar'/>);
    }
}

const Foo = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        someString: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
    , render: function() {
        return (<span>{this.props.someString}</span>);
    }
}
```

I guess a use case is detecting mistypings of optional parameters.

Comment: This is not really ideal as many libraries injects props and let the users use the props on demand, such as `react-router`. Isn't `.isRequired` for all necessary props sufficient to catch typos?